# How to connect to arbitary DOM elements using draggable in jQuery?

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

I've found a article that explains how to connect draggable elements to **sortable** ones:

http://the-stickman.com/files/jquery/draggable-sortable.html

But what I need is to connect draggable elements to **arbitary** DOM elements,

I need to do something when I drop it on some element.

But how know the element that the draggable is on when I drop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a droppable, and use $(this) inside the ondrop function you set to refer to the droppable, and then do the connection.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop

I believe that should do it, unless I misunderstand your problem.